# Flutter GetX Custom Theme for Button

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-theme

I have written my custom theme like this and stored it in Get storage.

```
class Themes {
  static final lightTheme = ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(),
    outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
        textStyle: TextStyle(
          color: CustomColor.lightLandingScreenTextColor,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );

  static final darkTheme = ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark(),
    outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        textStyle: TextStyle(
          color: CustomColor.darkLandingScreenTextColor,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Then I tried to apply my `outlinedbutton` theme on my `outlinedbutton` like this

```
SizedBox(
  height: 48.h,
  width: 155.w,
  child: OutlinedButton(
           onPressed: () {},
           child: Text("SKIP"),  
           style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(),
         ),)
```

I also tried to assign a theme like this but this gave me an error.

[image]

Now how can I assign that custom button theme to my button? I am using GetX for state management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use like this

```
style: context.theme.outlinedButtonTheme.style
```

you are trying to add `OutlinedButtonThemeData` in a parameter type `'ButtonStyle?'` that's why giving error.